# Display filtered Firebase data in UItableview

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, xcode8

I have a structure called artists which contains id, artistName, artistGenre and artistCountry. 
[Screenshot for clarification.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpi43.png)
I want to filter the data and show the artists with `artistCountry = "Asgard"` in a tableview

This is what I'm doing now:

```
let query = Database.database().reference().child("artists").queryOrdered(byChild: "artistCountry").queryEqual(toValue: "Asgard")
    query.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount >= 0{
            self.artistsList.removeAll()
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            print((snap as! DataSnapshot).childSnapshot(forPath: "artistName"))
            //getting values
            let artistObject = (snap as AnyObject).value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let artistName = artistObject?["artistName"]
            let artistGenre = artistObject?["artistGenre"]
            let artistCountry = artistObject?["artistCountry"]
            let artistId = artistObject?["id"]
            //creating artists object with model and fetched values
            let artist = artistModel(id: artistId as! String?, name: artistName as! String?, genre: artistGenre as! String?, country: artistCountry as! String?)
            //adding to array
            self.artistsList.append(artist)

        }
            self.tblArtists.reloadData()

        }
    })
```

Using the array `artistList` to display in the table. However I'm getting an error stating "Ambiguous use of 'value'" in `let artistObject = (snap as AnyObject).value as? [String: AnyObject]`

How can I add the filtered data to the array and display them in the tableview?

Comment: I don't know how `DataSnapshot`is defined. But since your `print` statement apparently was executed without errors, why not to use `let artistObject = (snap as! DataSnapshot).value as? [String: AnyObject]`?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner thank you so much, never thought of that. It worked.